# Setting Probes for SimVision in Verilog Code

Tags: verilog, simulation, cadence

I am working on simulations of verilog builded digital logic and need to restart a simulation very often to see the changes. I am using Cadence SimVision to review the waveforms.

Is there a way to write commands in verilog for the SimVision environment? I mean things like probes and Parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It is not Verilog but you can create a tcl file.

shm.tcl:

```
database -open waves -shm
probe -create your_top_level -depth all -all -shm -database waves
run 
exit
```

Now to run your simulation use:

```
irun -access +r testcase.sv -input shm.tcl
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not standard Verilog, but the Cadence tools (ncvlog, ncsim, Incisive) will allow you to set probes from within the Verilog/SV source using a system call.

Check for documentation for `$shm_open` and `$shm_probe`.

```
initial begin
  $shm_open("waves.shm");
  $shm_probe("AS");
end
```

That said, the answer from @Morgan is the recommended way to do it so that you can control it at runtime.